# Delete a marker in Baidu Map js Api

Tags: javascript, baidu-map

I want to delete the marker which I have added to the map.
However, when I add the marker by the function invoked in the javascript code, I can delete it correctly, but when I add the marker by the add button, I can not delete this marker. Is there any difference in the two lines code?
The delete demo given by Baidu Map: [Delete marker](http://lbsyun.baidu.com/jsdemo.htm#c1_17)

Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
    body, html {width: 100%;height: 100%;margin:0;font-family:"微软雅黑";}
    #allmap{width:100%;height:500px;}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.map.baidu.com/api?v=2.0&ak=38XkbdMoTDz7oYXNxnmcyvXLFNgIuDNv"></script>
<title>Delete specific marker</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="allmap"></div>

    <input type="button" onclick="addMarker(116.417029, 39.903252,null,'123');" value="add"/>
        <input type="button" onclick="deletePoint('123')" value="delete id=123"/>
</body>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript">
// 百度地图API功能
map = new BMap.Map("allmap");
point = new BMap.Point(116.404, 39.915);
map.centerAndZoom(point, 15);
map.disableDoubleClickZoom(true);

// 编写自定义函数,创建标注
function addMarker(lng, lat,iconName, labelContent){
        var p = new BMap.Point(lng, lat);
        var marker = new BMap.Marker(p, {icon:iconName});
        var label = new BMap.Label(labelContent,{offset:new BMap.Size(20,-10)});
        map.addOverlay(marker);
        marker.setLabel(label);
        //marker.setTitle(labelContent);
        marker.setAnimation(BMAP_ANIMATION_BOUNCE);
}
var commandPeopleIcon = new BMap.Icon("icon/people.png", new BMap.Size(47,37));
var tankIcon = new BMap.Icon("icon/tank.png", new BMap.Size(50, 50));
// 随机向地图添加25个标注
var bounds = map.getBounds();
var sw = bounds.getSouthWest();
var ne = bounds.getNorthEast();
var lngSpan = Math.abs(sw.lng - ne.lng);
var latSpan = Math.abs(ne.lat - sw.lat);
for (var i = 0; i < 0; i++) {
    var lng = sw.lng + lngSpan * (Math.random() * 0.7);
    var lat = ne.lat - latSpan * (Math.random() * 0.7);

    addMarker(lng, lat, tankIcon, "id="+i);
}
function deletePoint(agentName){
    var allOverlay = map.getOverlays();
            alert(allOverlay.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < allOverlay.length -1; i++){
        //var name = allOverlay[i].getLabel().content;
                  //var title = allOverlay[i].getTitle();
                    //alert(name);
        var className = allOverlay[i]["V"]["classList"][0];
        //alert(className);
        if (className == 'BMap_Marker') {
            var label = allOverlay[i].getLabel();
            if (label == null) {
                alert('label is null');
                continue;
            }
            alert(allOverlay[i].getLabel().content);
            if(allOverlay[i].getLabel().content == agentName){
                alert('delete');
                map.removeOverlay(allOverlay[i]);
                return false;
            }
        }   
    }
}
// if I add marker here, I can click delete button to delete the marker.
//addMarker(116.417029, 39.903252,null,'123');
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

To add Marker,

```
var mp = new BMap.Map("container");
var marker = new BMap.Marker(point);
mp.addOverlay(marker);
```

To remove Marker,

```
mp.removeOverlay(marker);
```

Comment: It may be annoying to you, but please excuse me for this. Can you please try to answer my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58185062/why-close-button-is-not-displayed-for-info-window-opened-on-baidu-map 
It is about Why close button is not displayed for info window opened on Baidu Map?